# SQL Server Merge Replication Change Partition Definition

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am using Merge Replication on a few SQL Server 2008 R2 servers.  There is one server, and the rest are clients.

I have each of the clients on a different partition using row filters with the `HOST_NAME()` function.

This works as expected, but I can't seem to figure out how to change this value after creating the subscription.

I need to change this value for all of the subscriptions and I would like to avoid dropping and recreating them.

How can I change the `HOST_NAME()` value for a subscriber without dropping/recreating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

1. Go to the merge agent that handles the subscriber that you would like to change.
2. Right click -> Properties
3. Go to the `Steps` page and edit the `Run agent` step
4. Add or Alter the `HostName` parameter like so:  `-HostName [<Your Value Here>]`
5. Stop & Start the agent job
6. Reinitialize the subscription.

That should do it!